# How many kinds of average are there?

Tags: statistics, average

I have learned that the mean, median and mode are three kinds of average.

Are there other kinds of average or are there just these three ?

Comment: There are as many as you want there to be with the ability to make more at will.  If you are explicitly referring to "*averages*" and you are specifically referring to commonly used averages, then at the least you should also include the geometric mean in your list.  The geometric mean of positive numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ is given by $\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n}$

Comment: A fairly common family of generalized means are the Henon means -- for a positive data set [$a,b,c,...$], and integer $n$, form the quotient (sum of (n+1)-st powers) / (sum of n-th powers). For $n=0$ this is the (arithmetic) mean, $n= -1$ is harmonic mean, $n=2$ is sometimes called contra-harmonic mean. But any $n$ gives a quantity satisfying some basic properties you'd want in something you'd call an "average" -- a single number thats somehow represents the data set.

Comment: Mean, median, and mode are also known as measures of central tendency.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Summary_of_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main categories of averages. One, mathematical averages focus on using mathematical tools to find the "average". These are Arithmetic, Geometric, and Harmonic Means. The Positionals are concerned with finding values within the data set only, these are Median and Mode. However, if you wish to, you can arbitrarily create new "averages" for usage in different situations with finding values within the data set only.